# how to filter on a JavaScript object based on its attributes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript object

```
 var items = { ids : [
  {
    label: "red",
    complete: true
  },
  {
    label: "green",
    complete: false
  },
  {
    label: "blue",
    complete: true
  }
]

}
```

I need to filter out based on the complete attribute when I click on the complete button or when I click on all button it show show me all the entries.

How can I do this in the same function

I have this function which takes the list DOM element and creates the entries accordingly. I am wondering how could I write this function such that it could filter on the complete status or print all the entries in the redraw function itself.

```
 var redraw = function(items) {
     list.innerHTML='';
     for (var id in items) {
       draw(model.todos[id], list);
     }
 };

  var draw = function(Obj, container) {
      var el = Template.cloneNode(true);
      el.setAttribute('data-id', Obj.id);
      container.appendChild(el);
       update(Obj);
});
```

}

Comment: drawTodo in redraw method is a typo , it should be draw()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new function called `filterItems` that accepts the `items` array and `key` and `value` parameters and returns a filtered array based on those parameters. Then, just call it from `redraw` with the correct arguments.

```
function filterItems(items, key, value) {
  return items.ids.filter(function (el) {
    return el[key] === value;
  });
}

var redraw = function(items) {
  list.innerHTML='';
  items = filterItems(items, 'complete', true);
  for (var id in items) {
    draw(model.todos[id], list);
  }
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7DYnA/)

Comment: thanks , but when i use this, i see an error at filterItems i.e uncaught type error: undefined is not a function here is how i am doing it

Comment: function filterItems(items, key, value) {
  return items.filter( function (el) {
    return el[key] === value;
  });
}
  /**
   * Clean the current ToDo list and add elements again
   **/
  var redrawUI = function(model, status) {
    var items;
    list.innerHTML='';
    if(status) {
      items = filterItems(model.todos, status, true)
    }
    items = model.todos
    for (var id in items) {
      drawTodo(items[id], list);
    }
  };

Comment: Because you're passing `model.todos` instead of `items`? `status` should be quoted. I'm not sure what `items = model.todos` is meant to be doing... Was there something wrong with `redraw` in my answer? Based on your question all you need to do is filter the items and them loop over the filtered array like you were doing...

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [];

for(var item in items.ids){
  if(items.ids[item].hasOwnProperty("complete") && 
     items.ids[item].complete === true){
    result.push(item);
  }
}
```

you can use this to filter out the items based on the complete attribute.

[demo](http://jsbin.com/rarez/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), this is pretty simple

```
var completedItems = {
  ids: _.filter(items.ids, function (id) { return id.complete; })
};
```

Otherwise you could write it by hand

```
var completedItems = {
  ids: (function (ids) {
    var arr = [];
    ids.forEach(function (id) {
      if (id.complete) arr.push(id);
    });
    return arr;
  })(items.ids)
};
```